# 3 table based relation display in yii gridview

Tags: php, gridview, yii

I am getting foreign key relation based display ids in the gridview. How to get values instead of ids? Please take a look of my gridview code:

```
$criteria->compare('department.UniversityNameid',$this->UniversityName, true);
```

my gridview inside code is:

```
array( 
         'name' => 'UniversityName',
         'type' => 'raw',
            'value'=>'(empty($data->department->UniversityNameid))? "" : Yii::app()->params["currencySymbol"]." ".$data->education->UniversityNameid',

   ),
```

Comment: What is the field you want displayed and how is it related to `$data`?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, as pointed out by topher. However, given the limited information, this is an example of a solution that might work.

**In your model:**

```
public function search()
    {
           $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
           $criteria->with= array('department','education'); //Related Models
           $criteria->compare('education.univ_name',$this->univ_name,true);
      ........
    }
```

**In your View:**

```
    array(
        'header' => 'University Name',
        'name' => 'univ_name',
        'value' => 'isset($data->education->univ_name) ? $data->education->univ_name : ""',
        ),
```